# Writing to the SD card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to write to the physical SD card in my Android phone.

This is my code:

```
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); //shows mounted
    boolean removable = Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(); //shows false
```

I know that the external in `getExternalStorageDirectory()` not necessarily means the SD card. When I write a file to sdCard object it ends up in the internal (means build in) storage and not on the sdCard.

On my mobile I have multiple apps which write data to the sdCard, e.g. file explorer. How do they do it? I want to force to write to sdCard regardless what the manufacturer thinks is internal/external.

Comment: any success with writing files in sdcard directly..?

Answer (score 0):

> **Caution:** Files on external storage are not always accessible, because users can mount the external storage to a computer for use as a storage device. So if you need to store files that are critical to your app's functionality, you should instead store them on internal storage.

---

> Request external storage permissions

To write to the public external storage, you must request the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in your manifest file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

> **Note**: If your app uses the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)  permission, then it implicitly has permission to read the external storage as well.

If your app only needs to read the external storage (but not write to it), then you need to declare the [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

---

Now, let's say that for example you want to record a text file in your SD ...

```
// get the path to sdcard
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// to this path add a new directory path
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/your-dir-name/");
// create this directory if not already created
dir.mkdir();
// create the file in which we will write the contents
File file = new File(dir, "My-File-Name.txt");
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
String data = "This is the content of my file";
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did, the question is why my file ends up on what is commonly considered the internal storage and not the micro SD card.

Answer (score 0):

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
...
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did, the question is why my file ends up on what is commonly considered the internal storage and not the micro SD card.

Comment: @AndyAndroid Because `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` doesn't work like it used to work anymore. Using a newer Android version, it now gives you the path to the external storage, which is the built in (not removable!) storage your phone came with. Getting access to the actual (removable) SD card is now a bit more complicated and, unless you need to write to a specific folder, there are a few questions here on SO that address how to do it.